# Please ban the [best-practises] tag

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tag-block-request

The `[best-practices]` tag is already banned on Stack Overflow, though there is a `[best-practises]` tag taking its spot among newcomers.

Related blog post: [The death of meta tags](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)

Comment: Why the downvote? I don't like that the meta tags were removed but I'd like things to be consistent.

Comment: I also saw `[best-practice]` a couple of days ago

Comment: Jeff needs to just add a regex for matching similar things so that `[c++-best-practices]` etc is also banned @Perp

Comment: `best-practice[s]`, `best-practise[s]`... what else? `standards`? `industry-standard[s]`? `common-programming-techniques`?

Comment: What happens if we retag those two questions (so there are 0 [best-practises]) and then propose it as a synonym of the banned [best-practices]? Will it blacklist that one too? Or will it circumvent the ban on [best-practices] and retag it anyway? (EDIT: Tried it: you can't propose a synonym of a tag that doesn't exist, it won't create it to do so)

Comment: *its*, not *it's*. Also, move *though* after StackOverflow.

Comment: @mcandre, I'll fix it; also, the preferred spelling is "Stack Overflow," with a space.

Comment: @Jon B: `[standards]` could be talking about *technical* standards -- for example, [RFC 2822](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822). (Huh. That's obsolete now? But I've never heard of [RFC 5322](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322) before...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a lot of related tags which could be banned as well. Search on `prac` in https://stackoverflow.com/tags. Most if not all of them can be wiped as well. Only `practical-programming` seems feasible. Some of the `practical` tags needs to retagged then.

---

**update**: I wiped the following (should maybe be added to blacklist as well?)

```
bad-practices
coding-practices
common-practice
practical-approach
practical-use
programming-practices
```

I'll wipe the remaining when I'm in a mood to do that ;) First a break.

Answer (score 1):

Newbies often ask things like `"how do i conkatenate strings best practise??? please help"` when they don't even have bad-practice working code. I champion such tags, even though they are overused.

I often write code I don't approve of and would like to know if there is a more elegant or at least more standard way to code. I'd hate to get into the habit of creating numbered variables and learn a year later about arrays, to name a trivial example.

Comment: Well, there's often a reasonably wide gulf between the "best" way to do something and any number of "not completely horrible" ways to do the same. I suspect most users asking for "best" don't really know what that would look like anyway: best in terms of maintainability, best in terms of performance, ...? Merely asking, "How should I concatenate strings" followed by some specific information would probably suffice - and that's what I'd edit it into anyway.

Comment: Maybe "idiomatic and good" would be a better way to put it.