# Can't keep a good tag down!

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, tag-block-request

As might have been expected, now that [beginner](/questions/tagged/beginner) has been expunged, [newbie](/questions/tagged/newbie) is starting to take its place!

Comment: The same thing is happening with [best-practices and best-practises](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60240/please-ban-the-best-practises-tag).  Perhaps we should merge questions like these into one "list of banned tag synonyms" question?  (That's {banned tag} synonyms, not banned {tag synonyms}.)

Comment: if we have to choose, my vote is definitely for [beginner]...

Comment: Hmmm, another tag taking the place of a banned one. [Where have I heard that before?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51627/should-we-permanently-remove-the-subjective-tag/51640#51640) ;)

Comment: @gnovice: Time to change back to gnostradamus?

Comment: @mmyers: "Every time I try to get out, they keep pulling me back in!"

Comment: @gnovice: I don't think anybody would have predicted otherwise - but 10 questions tagged `[newbie]` are easier to deal with than 5000 questions tagged `[beginner]`.  Surely we can deal with these little flare-ups individually with the synonyms feature.

Comment: @Aarobot: I was really just joking a bit with my comment, but on a more serious note, how exactly does one create a tag synonym for a tag that has been banned? Normally, you create a synonym by going to the info page for that tag, but there *is no* page for a banned tag (at least not one I have found yet).

Comment: @gnovice: You can still type the tag page into the address bar and get the info page, but it won't let you add a synonym.  I assume that diamond mods can do this, though, and if not, certainly the admins can do it on the back-end.  (Once we weed out the first few blacklist-workaround-tag attempts, I doubt that it'll come up often enough to matter.)

Comment: There already was a [newbie] -> [beginner] synonym, so probably that was deleted when the tag was banned.

Comment: How is this happening? I thought only high-rep users could create tags.

Comment: @Andrew If someone has already created a tag, then even if it is reduced to 0 in count someone will be able to add it to a question. As well, a lot of these tags did exist from very early on in the site and were simply never cleaned up, like [opinion].

Comment: @Grace Note: I thought zombie tags were killed at the end of the day!

Answer (score 6):

SO needs a, `This tag will self-destruct in 10, 9, 8, ...` If you don't remove the tag in time, not only will the tag be destroyed but your question too.

Comment: ... And your monitor.

Comment: @mmyers You leave my Monitor out of this!

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party as usual, here is the related entry from the [Tag Synonyms Repository](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50088/official-repository-of-tag-synonyms/50089#50089) if a mod wants to do anything with it:

**`[beginner]`**: `[beginners]`, `[newbie]`, `[newb]`, `[n00b]`, `[noob]`, `[new-user]`, `[new-users]`, `[new-developer]`, `[new-developers]`, `[beginning]`

Comment: As of today, none of those tags are in use on SO.  (Since I didn't see any update here.)