# [opinion] the same as [subjective]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-block-request

[opinion](/questions/tagged/opinion) is pretty much the same thing as [subjective](/questions/tagged/subjective) and is being tagged onto questions [in the same manner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467228/best-language-for-webdevelopment-with-fast-calculates-closed) (now deleted, 10k+ only). Time to blacklist?

Comment: 145 questions tagged [opinion] already!

Comment: @ChrisF i was surprised it got this far too, seems like an obvious one.

Comment: +1 There were 5 on SF.  Now there are 0.

Comment: I tried linking it to [subjective] as a synonym but failed :(

Comment: There were 6 on SU. Now there are 0.

Comment: Let the eradication begin?

Comment: This will never end. Up next: `[not-objective]`

Comment: @Jon B If only we had some way of limiting the number of words people would come up with.... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newspeak

Comment: @james - `[double-plus-subjective]`

Comment: [I saw it coming](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51627/should-we-permanently-remove-the-subjective-tag/51640#51640), and again [I saw it coming](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60343/should-some-forbidden-tags-still-have-an-active-tag-wiki-and-tag-synonyms). Damn, I'm good!

Comment: @gnostradamus: you are aptly named!

Comment: @gnostradamus: <nitpick> "Prophesy" is a verb; "prophecy" is the noun form. </nitpick>

Comment: @mmyers: Corrected. Also, I knew you were going to say that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blacklist? How 'bout, make [opinion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opinion) into a kiss of death: Go through the questions so-tagged, and vote to close them. If they're already closed, vote to delete them. If they don't deserve either, then re-tag them.

Comment: Hmmm. That should keep some busy for a day or two. Until the fun wears off.

Comment: -1 Not sure a declaration of war is the best way forward.

Comment: @MarkJ: no, a fresh coat of white-wash will put things right for sure *this time*...

Comment: @Shog9 at ~150 questions, i'm not that motivated...

Comment: @James: no one is. That's why [subjective] dominated...

Comment: @Shog9, perhaps we could organize some sort of cleanup, where we all get together and clean the database of anything resembling a subjective question.  It would be just like park clean ups! We could even make t-shirts.

Comment: @James: that is a rather good idea...

Comment: +1 @Mark: Declaration of war is *always* the best way forward.

Comment: OMG, uniforms! You people really **are** about to **declare war**!

Comment: Sounds good; I was getting bored after the [hidden-features] skirmishes ended and have been looking around for a new target. Arming photon torpedos now.

Answer (score 5):

Ex-ter-min-ate!  Ex-ter-min-ate!

Seriously, this is even more vacuous than "subjective".  I have a lot of opinions, and varying amounts of objective support for them.  Many of them are shared very widely, and I introduce some of them into all but the most objective questions (like "Is this valid according to the Standard?").

My opinion, which is only somewhat subjective, is that "opinion" is worse in every way than "subjective".

Comment: So let's ban opinion. And then ban whatever comes after. And ban again, and again, and again... Or, just maybe, this meta tag deletion thing isn't working. Who would have thought it? Oh, look: [this post predicts the problem in advance](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51627/should-we-permanently-remove-the-subjective-tag/51640#51640) and is the top-voted post on the suggestion to permanently remove subjective.

Comment: @markj you're missing the fact that certain tags were allowed to "take root" early on and cause behaviorial problems later. We won't be repeating that mistake.