# Please blacklist the [noob] tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-block-request

**[[noob]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/noob)** is making a slow come back; there were 8 questions today.

Could this tag be either black listed or transformed into an actual word?

Currently [noob] pops up in the tag auto complete feature, but [beginner] does not.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60318/cant-give-a-question-a-good-title

Comment: @Grace Note - thanks for the link. I followed some more links from there. I'm still unclear as to the SOP for bad tags. A request post, or add it to the synonyms list (noob is already there) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50088/official-repository-of-tag-synonyms/50089#50089 or what?

Comment: Looks like all of them are gone.

Comment: @KennyTM - Since there were so few, I edited them out; but `noob` still pops up in the tag autocomplete, so I'm sure it'll be back.

Comment: Once the cache expires, it won't appear (until it's used again).  Thanks for editing them out.

Comment: is there a thread that 'debates' whether or not the noob tag is useful? Or is it just generally not liked by non-noobs

Answer (score 2):

It should be synonymed to `newbie` or `beginner`, if those tags haven't been burned at the stake.

Comment: @Lance - This does not appear to be possible, as there are no pages for the `"newbie"` or `"beginner"` tags - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beginner http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/newbie

Comment: @Peter, I was afraid of that, they got rid of all 'Meta' tags on SO a little while ago, but never came up with viable alternatives.

Comment: @Lance Roberts:  What would constitute a viable alternative that would accord with Jeff's policy on tags?  His decision was that these tags added nothing useful to tagging the question as opposed to the questioner.  In particular, "noob", "n00b", "beginner", etc. are useless at describing the question because a beginner has no good idea of whether a question is near-trivial or deep and complex.

Comment: @David, I don't necessarily have the answer for what is a viable alternative, but the point is that there is information there that no longer exists.  So in this case if a beginner wanted a post that explained things from a novice perspective, he will not be able to search for that.  In the case of the `subjective` tag, now people won't be able to filter those out (and no, I don't think those questions are appropriate for the site, but they exist).

Comment: @Lance Roberts:  The tags are on questions, not answers.  A novice might want to find answers that are elementary, but an elementary-looking question might have deep answers and a complicated-looking question might have simple answers.  Moreover, a novice is incapable of knowing what complexity category a question is in.  I've seen newbies asking very simple questions, and questions with very involved answers.  So, I don't see what good a "noob" tag is when applied to a question.  If we voted on the simplicity of answers, and were able to search on that, that might be worthwhile.

Comment: @Lance Roberts: If I could give you 100 up votes I would.  As a beginner, I used to be able to find interesting/relevant content easily (beginner tag was a big part of this).  Post the death of meta-tags, SO's value to me/other beginners has fallen sharply.