# Blacklist the [plz-send-teh-codez] tag?

Tags: discussion, tag-block-request, meta-tags

I think we should blacklist the [plz-send-teh-codez](/questions/tagged/plz-send-teh-codez) (and possibly variations<sup>1</sup> thereof).  There are not currently any questions tagged as such (anymore), but at least one user ([this person](https://stackoverflow.com/users/249538/chris)) has been actively trying to resurrect it ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8459107/revisions), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8499642/revisions), and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8592162/revisions)).

All three instances above happened this month.  But, I think this tag was *intentionally wiped out of existence*<sup>2</sup>, and is now trying to creep back in (which, according to [this statement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/102174/168428) by Jeff Atwood, makes it a possible candidate for blacklisting).

What does everyone think?

---

<sup>1</sup>Things like [plzsendtehcodez](/questions/tagged/plzsendtehcodez) and [tehcodezcanyouplzsendthem](/questions/tagged/tehcodezcanyouplzsendthem); I doubt there is a (legitmate) need for any tag containing "plz" or "codez"

<sup>2</sup> Based on a comment by a mod on the [third post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592162/ranking-document-based-on-searched-terms) above:

> Indeed. That tag used to be pretty common, but we *finally*
>   got rid of it. Please don't start it again, @chris. – Michael Myers♦ 2
>   hours ago

<sup>Additional Note</sup> The tag was common enough at one point to gain [a place among the many of meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19780#19780), which actually states:

> It is now considered bad practice to apply the tag to a question and users should remove it as necessary.

Comment: The temptation to add [plz-send-the-banz] to this is almost irresistible.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10078/whats-the-difference-between-an-obvious-homework-question-and-one-tagged-plzsen for background.

Comment: Someone recreates it *at least* once a week.  I'd love to see it go on the blacklist.

Comment: @GhostofChristmasPresents Thanks for that context, that's helpful (although the answers made me a little dizzy).

Comment: I wonder how many varients of `plzsendtehcodez` you can make.

Answer (score 5):

Retagging questions this way seems to be rather uncommon and quickly rolled back, so I don't think it's enough of a problem that it requires massive blacklisting of countless possible variations of the tag.

Simply rolling back such edits seems to work fine.

Comment: `countless possible variations` - agree. Just like people got around the "Problem" filter, people will get around this one.  You can't fix stupid.

Comment: I just mean that they should ban it in the same way they've done [help](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102165/please-blacklist-the-help-tag), [noob](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63113/please-blacklist-the-noob-tag), [not-working and error](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95513/not-working-tag), and others.  It's not perfect, but that doesn't mean we shouldn't take steps to remove  an unwanted tag that keeps coming back @AdamRackis.

Comment: @AdamRackis OMG ARE YOU GONNA CITE RON WHITE OR WHAT

Comment: @bob - sure - why not :-)