# Is it a good idea for me to try to find a home here?

Tags: discussion

I was pretty hyped to come to Stack Overflow and I want to contribute and talk about coding on my [Raspberry Pi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi). But... I have been pretty discouraged here.  I can't ask questions where I want to. I can't answer easy questions I know the answer to.  I'm afraid to ask questions because it looks like everything just gets downvoted or deleted.

I don't have this problem anywhere else, like Reddit. Is it worth it to try to keep going here? I'm pretty bummed out about the experience here.

Comment: As this question is about a situation on *one specific site* in the Stack Exchange network, unfortunately, we have to mark this question as "off-topic" for this site. Questions on this site, Meta Stack Exchange, are expected to relate to the entire SE network as a whole, not just one specific site. I do see where you're coming from, though, and there's a discussion over on the Stack Overflow specific meta that addresses this: [Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What should I do if I am afraid to post for fear of downvote hell?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342844/282094) and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341731/282094

Comment: Has anyone advised you to try looking at the [raspberrypi.se] stack? You may have had a negative reception before for posting in the wrong place.

Comment: Yes Rob, I read those and they do help a bit. Thanks for the link @Tantalus' touch. I will check it out.

Comment: I'll be reopening  this with the view of posting an answer later. I do urge folks to look beyond the letter of the question and look more at the user and their needs

Comment: @JourneymanGeek This is probably still the wrong question to ask here, but I think my question I should have asked is something like "Hey (newer) members, I'm feeling bad right now is it worth the initial trouble to start an account?" But I already like the replies I have gotten, the Raspberry Pi link especially. So, it seems worth it.

Comment: Well - I don't think its wrong, just that folks thought it was something it wasn't too quickly based off the surface.

Comment: Yes, please stay! If your posts get downvoted, that's not because we don't like you, but because you didn't follow some social norms (that weren't even communicated to you properly). Once you learn the 'local customs', it gets better.

Comment: Thanks @HolyBlackCat I will keep trying to learn, just being able to talk about it has made me feel better. And the insight from some of these comments that were reaching out are really nice.

Comment: Re *"I can't ask questions where I want to. I can't answer easy questions I know the answer to"*: Do you mean literally? Or because of fear? Perhaps rephrase to make it more clear?

Answer (score 7):

There's a bit of a broader network, and many smaller spaces than SO (Stack Overflow) that often might fit your needs or you might find it friendlier. To be fair, in the past, the people who run the company forget there's a network outside SO at times, even if we keep reminding them.

Part of the problem is, of course, that many of the spaces that are useful, outside core SO, or even core Q&A aren't that easy to find. Our social "hubs" are chat, but they're hard to find, and outside the bigger sites, as such not very well used. Not a good place to ask questions in many cases, but useful in getting the feel of a community, and sometimes getting advice.

I've had a decade, and started off on a very different, and smaller network. I never did find a home on SO, being a non-developer. I took like a dog to mud on Super User, since I did... general computery stuff, and ended up on Meta (and I'm a moderator here, so I *guess* I got accepted here) in the course of my duties as a moderator on Super User and on meta.

I doubt anyone will ever find a "home" on just core Q&A - that needs community, and, as the old joke goes, "It's social software for anti-social people".

Helping our new users ease in is an ongoing thing, with many sides. It's worth remembering that there's other aspects of the network - chat for example that are a little less intimidating, as well as other sites.

We have a specialist sites for [Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com), though you might find [Super User](https://superuser.com) useful as a generalist site and [Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com)  is often great for deeper more technical subjects (just not [Kali](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me), unless you actually know what you're doing).

It's also worth remembering that the "experienced" users didn't get there overnight. It takes time to work out some of the more peculiar aspects of the network, and a lot of the 'rules' we have now evolved as the community grew.  Some of those rules are codified - others, well, are less so.

Whether it's a good idea is entirely up to you. That said–you might find some sites work better than others, or that there's some point where you 'get it' with a little patience.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write that, it made me feel a lot better and less of an outsider. It kind of takes an outsider to know how an outsider might feel?  By the way, I am now writing this whole thing with a smile on my face because of "Its social software for anti-social people" - yeah I'm something of an introvert, I'm pretty sure extroverts don't feel as easily rejected.  When you talk about chat that is hard to find are you talking about IRC? Do you recommend any?

Comment: No! We actually have chat integral to the network, and many sites have active chatrooms. Unfortunately, the links are hidden away - in the old days they were front and center, and now they're in the site switcher. Its a pity - since SE chat is really good. Looking at your reputation - you should be able to get on the MSE chat server (MSE and SO have their own chat servers, and everyone else shares one), and many sites have one or more chatrooms.

Answer (score 2):

Stack Overflow (and any Stack Exchange main site) is a place to ask professional questions and get professional answers. Period.

One can stick around, which is more than welcome, but "talking about code" sounds like you look for a place to just discuss programming, and that's not what Stack Overflow is for.

You can discuss things related to the site on the meta site and in chat, to some limit.

Bottom line: you can't expect the old time members to make you feel at home from the very beginning, and surely not on the main site. Hang around, ask good questions and/or post helpful answers, become part of the community, and you'll eventually feel at home.