# Blacklist the "getting-started" tag

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, tag-block-request

In my opinion, [getting-started](/questions/tagged/getting-started) is unnecessary among a question's other tags. Moreover, many questions with this tag are off-topic or not constructive.

Therefore, I suggest removing this tag from all questions that have it, and then blacklisting that tag.

[image]

Comment: It's only 183 questions, and it doesn't seem like the [questions are coming in with this tag at such a fast clip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/getting-started?sort=newest&pagesize=50) so I'd recommend doing the tag cleanup which should stop low-rep users from creating the tag.

Comment: I will do that.  I intended the blacklist to happen after most questions are stripped of this tag.  I encourage users to help.

Comment: Hmm, someone wrote a [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/getting-started/info) for that tag that should have never been approved. This isn't a useful tag in the first place, and the tag wiki seems to indicate that it should be used for precisely what people are using it for.

Comment: I'm cleaning up the tag as we speak as it is a 'meta' tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have removed the [getting-started](/questions/tagged/getting-started) tag from all questions bar 25 which I couldn't edit as I have done too many suggest edits today, but they have to be peer reviewed as I don't have enough rep on Stack Overflow yet.

Comment: I've been approving them for you as that tag is an eyesore. Thanks for making the edits!

Comment: @jmort253 Thanks for approving them

Comment: Well, now I'm in your shoes. I'm out of review votes. Ironically enough, someone was voting to reject some of the getting-started tag removals. Perhaps there should be a way to separate retagging from actual editing, as they probably thought you weren't editing enough and didn't understand that you were just cleaning up tags...

Comment: @jmort253 Thanks for your help, if anyone else can read this please help!

Comment: @jmort253 - At 500 rep, you get the [retag-questions privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/retag-questions).  That should be used instead of the edit feature for anyone over 500 rep *when the question doesn't need to be edited*.  A bunch of these do need editing because they're from users who are, well, getting started.

Comment: @Kevin - I don't see the retag question option on SO where I have 5900 rep. I see the "retag question" option on PMSE, where I'm a mod, but I don't see that on SO. I just assumed it was a mod feature. On SO, I've always retagged by editing.

Comment: @KevinVermeer - Looks like that link "retag questions" is [only possible for users with 500 to 2000 rep, then 10k users and mods](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88151/what-is-the-reason-for-removing-the-retag-link-for-users-with-full-editing-right). In other words, it sounds like once you hit 2000 rep, retagging disappears until you hit 10k. Odd...

Comment: @jmort253 - Yeah, sorry, I meant over 500 rep and under 2000.  The end result is that, as desired, no one over 500 rep should suggest an edit to retag a question.

Comment: @Benny - So according to what we just found, you should be able to retag questions using the retag questions link, if you either hover your mouse to the right of the tags, or look for the link next to the edit option. This means you should be able to continue your journey towards exterminating the Getting Started tag, even though you've exhausted your suggested edits. :)

Comment: @jmort253 I don't have 500 rep on SO

Comment: @Benny - no worries. I think one of the SE devs is just going to get rid of the tag in the backend, so no need to intervene any further :)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I recall, [used tags are not blacklisted](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/716/199). The tag should be removed from the questions using it, and then it would be blacklisted.
As I understand the answer given to that question, it means that if there are still 3 questions using it, the tag will not be blacklisted.

Comment: As I understand it, a tag blacklist request implies a burnination.  It's senseless to ask users to edit these tags manually when it's just a couple clicks for a mod.

Comment: @KevinVermeer burnination == remove tags from all existing questions, blacklist == prevent them from being used ever again. Latter's reserved for extreme cases

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the fact that the getting started tag is applied to low quality or not constructive questions, it's important to note that the Getting Started tag is at its core a meta tag.

Meta tags don't tell someone viewing the question on the front page whether or not the question has any relevance to anything that he or she would have experience with. A question tagged "Getting Started" could be about something I'm intimately familiar with, like JavaScript, or it could describe something for which I have little experience, like Underwater Basket-weaving.

The [Best practices](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60240/155826) tag is another example of a Meta tag that has been placed on the chopping block. Like the Getting Started tag, it tells me nothing about whether or not it's something I'm interested in or something I can help with.

In other words, to gauge the topic of the question, I still have to actually view the question. Tags should help us quickly identify questions we have an interest in while also helping us avoid the ones that have no value to us personally.

Tags, like everything else on Stack Overflow, should be devoid of distraction and clutter, and this means that any tags that don't specifically identify the question subject-matter should be banned, blacklisted, and escorted off our network.