# Why can't I vote to migrate from MSE?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, vote-to-close, migration

There is a close reason allowing to close the question because it "pertains to specific site". Why is there no possibility to vote for migration to some other site (often per-site meta, especially MSO) from MSE?

Comment: The system is currently limited to 5 migration paths. An alternative with an input field to choose a site was suggested [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/140755/167646).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here would that the list would have to include *every* meta site in the network.

While it could be done, it would mean either:

a. Breaking the "no more than 5 sites in the list" rule - and quite substantially!

or:

b. Showing a drop down/auto complete box for users to type into.

Option b. is possible - that element exists for moderators who can migrate anywhere, but I don't know how hard it would be to enable for all eligible users on single site.

The other drawback here is that at least three users would have to pick the same site for the migration to work. You might say that it's obvious but there's no guarantee that this will happen and the question would just get closed in place as now.

It's probably far simpler to close as now and then flag the question for a CM to migrate.

Comment: At least we should be able to migrate to MSO. There are many questions that after the big split belong to MSO.

Comment: @nicael - the problem with those is that the vast majority are older than 60 days and can't be migrated anyway.

Comment: Yes, didn't thought about it...

Comment: @nicael Actually, the problem is that the vast majority of questions that pertain just to SO wouldn't actually do anyone any favors by being migrated to MSO. *Many* of them should just be deleted because they're no longer relevant or useful (for example, [a status-completed post from 2010 that only has a score of 2](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60240/please-ban-the-best-practises-tag)...)