# Add site recommendation when flagging off topic

Tags: feature-request, flags, off-topic

There's an option "This question only pertains to a specific site" when flagging "off-topic".

Is it possible to add a box which asks you about the site that the question belongs to, and auto posts the site recommendation as a comment?

Is it also possible if a majority of off-topic votes think that the question belongs to the same specific site, it auto move it to the site? It seems unclear when the close message only says "this question doesn't power the SE network".

Comment: A bit related: [Why can't I vote to migrate from MSE?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242654/why-cant-i-vote-to-migrate-from-mse)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

People can leave comments already if they know what site a question belongs on. If the question is high-quality, and one of the close voters is active enough on the correct site to know its scope, they'll usually recommend reposting it in the right place. The problem with making this mandatory is that many questions asked just don't belong anywhere on Stack Exchange, so there's no correct site to suggest.

Comment: Only add the box on questions that belong to other sites? (I think I mentioned that)

Comment: @ArceusMaster0493 And how is the software supposed to know that the question belongs on another site? People tell it. Like they can already do in a comment. If we automate this process then a lot of low-quality questions will get migrated automatically. That's not necessary, as people can already use comments to tell each other when a good question belongs somewhere else, so it can be moved manually.

Answer (score 4):

People already volunterily add comments saying *"this question that just says' pls fix my codes' should be posted on StackOverflow"*. That is unhelpful enough when people do that without knowing what is suitable on said target site. Actually *encouraging* people to take a guess at where a question should be posted would be even more dangerous.

It would mean people would go and repost their really poor question on another site (duplicating content) only for the question to be closed off there too. And they will comment *"well they told me over at site X that I should post it here!?!"* That's a very bad user experience for all involved.

Most Off Topic questions posted on a site are either a) completely unsuitable for any other site, or b) posted intentionally on the wrong site because the use has been banned from posting on their original site.

Answer (score 1):

**This question only pertains to a specific site** is a Meta-specific close reason.

In general, letting people guess what site a question would be better on has not gone well. People with close vote privileges on Site A don't, as a rule, have a good idea what is on topic on Site B. ([My answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74053/require-minimum-reputation-on-the-target-site-for-migration/79646#79646) to a question about migrating might be relevant.) The other two answers both address this.

However, given that you're asking about this:

[image: close dialog]

I think it's a legitimate point. Someone who comes to this Meta and is asking about Travel, or Programmers, of Coffee - if we close the post we could say that it better belongs on that particular meta site. (The dialog could even be prepopulated with any site linked to in the body of the question.)

It may end up a dupe if the person asked there already. But it might save them a step and feel a little more friendly to just move it where it belongs.